# SQL Server Identity Seed

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a SQL Servier database where I store schedules for multiple companies in a table called tblSchedules.

The primary key for this table is `ScheduleRatesID` and auto increments.

Is there a way to have is increment from 700000 for Company A and 800000 for Company B?

Comment: same server, same database?

Comment: Why? A PK should not care what its value is. If you need something to differentiate a company. Why does tblSchedules not include a 'CompanyId'?

Comment: DO NOT store multiple pieces of information in a single column like this. It violates 1NF and will cause you untold amounts of anguish. What would happen to your number when you add the 1 millionth row for CompanyA? If you want to use a single table like this you should use two columns. One for the identity and one for the company.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them into two different tables and then use a view to union them together... I'm afraid that's your only option.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove the auto increment on this table and create a trigger to check on companyid, and based on companyid you must calculate and insert a unique primarykey in between the two different ranges you have specified.

Comment: This is not a good idea once you consider dealing with concurrency unless you have some mechanism to ensure that each new value is unique...oh wait identity already handles this with concurrency. Anytime you roll your own like this it is destined to run into the concurrency issue at some point.

Answer (score -1):

No. Identity does not work that way.

Sit down and write your own mechanism - it is not particularly hard.